# How to upload an image or a video to a persistant folder in class-path with Spring-Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, video, web, upload, storage

I am new in Spring-Boot...
I want to upload images or videos, and store them in a persistant folder "upload-storage" in the class-path of my project in the server. I don't want to store them in the database (20 Mo).
Spring-Boot store them in target/upload-storage.
That functions : I can show the videos on the view with the controller and Thymeleaf. I can close tomcat, close the browser, and open them again : that functions.
But the day after, upload-storage is disapeared !
I think that I don't use the good process.
But I found how to upload an image : ok. I found how to show images from a folder in class-path : ok. I found how to upload images to database. But nothing to store the uploaded images in a persistant folder.
Can you help me ? Can you tell me the good process ?

Some details :
I have an entity "video" to store name, extension, length,... of the video.
I have "VideoRepository" and "VideoService" to manage the requests with "Video".
I have a "StorageService" and "StorageServiceImpl" to manage the upload of video and images : It as to upload the video and save it in a folder called "upload-storage" : I will come back on it farther.
I have a videoForm.html first with a form to select a file and send it to "UploadController", then an other form to show the video, the datas extracted from the video, modify the name or add precisions, and send this form to a "VideoController" who save the entity.
A part of the code of "UploadController" :
`
    @Controller
    public class UploadController extends BaseController {

```
private final StorageService storageServiceImpl;

@Autowired
public UploadController(StorageService storageServiceImpl) {
    this.storageServiceImpl = storageServiceImpl;
}

@PostMapping("/upload")
public String recupereUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,Model model){
String filename ="";
try {
    final long limit = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
    if (file.getSize() > limit) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Taille du fichier trop grand (>200MB)");
        model.addAttribute("ok", false );
    }
    filename = storageServiceImpl.store(file);
    model.addAttribute("filename", filename);
    model.addAttribute("message", "Le téléchargement de " + filename+" est réussi !");
} catch (Exception e) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "FAIL to upload " + filename + "!");
    model.addAttribute("ok", false );
}
Video video = new Video();
model.addAttribute("ok", true ); 
model.addAttribute("video", video);
String baseName =  storageServiceImpl.getBaseName(filename);
String ext = storageServiceImpl.getExtension(filename);
model.addAttribute("nom", baseName);
model.addAttribute("ext", ext); 
model.addAttribute("nomorigin", filename);
model.addAttribute("size", Math.round(file.getSize()/1024));
String typExt = storageServiceImpl.getType(ext);
model.addAttribute("typExt", typExt);
return "elementVideo/videoForm";
}
```

`

"StorageServiceImpl" has different methods :

```
getExtension(String filename){...}
getType(String ext){...}
getType(String ext){...}
getBaseName(String filename){...}
```

The main method is store(MultipartFile file) {...}  :

```
@Service    
public class StorageServiceImpl implements StorageService {

private final Path storageLocation = Paths.get("upload-storage");

@Override
public String store(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        // Vérification de l'existence :
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to store empty file " + file.getOriginalFilename() ); 
        }
        // Vérification de la nature et traitement du fichier uploadé :
        String ext = getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
        String[] extAutorise = {"mp4", "avi","ogg","ogv","jpg","jpeg","png","gif"};
        String fileNameTarget ="";
        if ( ArrayUtils.contains( extAutorise, ext)) { 

            //Définir le fichier destination :
            fileNameTarget = file.getOriginalFilename();
            fileNameTarget = fileNameTarget.replaceAll(" ", "_");
            File dir = storageLocation.toFile();
            String serverFile =  dir.getAbsolutePath()  + File.separator + fileNameTarget ;
            try {
                try (InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
                     BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile))
                    ) {
                    int i;
                    while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
                        stream.write(i);
                    }
                    stream.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("error : " + e.getMessage());
            }
         }
         return fileNameTarget;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
    }
}
```

`
With this code, a folder "upload-storage" is created at the root of the project.
The video is uploaded in this folder...
But in "videoForm.html", the code

```
<video id="video" th:src="'/upload-storage/'+${filename}" height="60"
                        autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

shows nothing.
I have an other solution.
In StorageServiceImpl, I use the code :

```
private final String storageLocation = this.getClass().getResource("/static/").getPath();
```

at place of :

```
private final Path storageLocation = Paths.get("upload-storage");
```

then :

```
File dir = new File(storageLocation + File.separator + "upload-storage");
```

at place of :

```
File dir = storageLocation.toFile();
```

then :

```
File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileNameTarget);
```

at place of :

```
String serverFile =  dir.getAbsolutePath()  + File.separator + fileNameTarget ;
```

With this solution, upload-storage is created in target folder.

I use an other controller BaseController :

```
public class BaseController {
    public static final String PARAM_BASE_URL = "baseURL";
    public String getBaseURL(HttpServletRequest request){
        return request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
    }
}
```

`
UploadController extends this BaseController.
I add HttpServletRequest request in recupereUpload() :

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String recupereUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
Model model, HttpServletRequest request ){
```

I add in the model sent by recupereUpload :

```
model.addAttribute(PARAM_BASE_URL, getBaseURL(request));
```

And at last, I can see my video in videoForm.html with the code :

```
<video id="video" th:src="${baseURL}+'/upload-storage/'+${filename}" height="60" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

I can close Tomcat, close Eclipse, close the machine, and open all again : all is preserved and I can see the video.
But some time later : all is disappeared.
There must be a better solution.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for the video content portion of your solution?  That way you won't need to implement any of the video content handling.  Spring Content will provide this for you.  To add Spring Content to your project:

Add Spring Content to your classpath.

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-fs-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Associate content with your Video entity.

> Video.java

```
@Entity
public class Video {
   ...

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private Long contetLen;

   @MimeType
   private String mimeType;

   ...
```

Set up a "persistent folder" as the root of your video store.  This is where uploaded videos will be stored/streamed from.  Also create a `VideoStore` interface to describe to SC how you want to associate your content.

> SpringBootApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourSpringBootApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourSpringBootApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableFilesystemStores
  public static class StoreConfig {
    File filesystemRoot() {
        return new File("/path/to/your/videos");
    }

    @Bean
    public FileSystemResourceLoader fsResourceLoader() throws Exception {
      return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }

  @StoreRestResource(path="videos")
  public interface VideoStore extends ContentStore<Video,String> {
    //
  }
}
```

This is all you need to create a REST-based video service at `/videos`.  Essentially, when your application starts, Spring Content will look at your dependencies (seeing Spring Content FS/REST), look at your `VideoStore` interface and inject an implementation of that interface based on the filesystem.  It will also inject a controller that forwards http requests to that implementation as well.  This saves you having to implement any of this yourself.

So...

`POST /videos/{video-entity-id}`

with a multipart/form-data request will store the video in `/path/to/your/videos` and associate it with the video entity whose id is `video-entity-id`.

`GET /videos/{video-entity-id}`

will fetch it again.  This supports partial content requests or byte ranges; i.e. video streaming too.

and so on...support full CRUD.

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  The  reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/fs-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).  The coding bit starts about 1/2 way through.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the upload by adding the following property in the application.properties file?

```
## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

I have written an article about how to upload a multipart file in spring boot using thymeleaf. Here is the service used for the upload.

```
   package com.uploadMultipartfile.storage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

@Service
public class FileSystemStorageService implements StorageService
{
    private final Path rootLocation;

    @Autowired
    public FileSystemStorageService(StorageProperties properties) {
        this.rootLocation = Paths.get(properties.getUploadDir()).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(this.rootLocation);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new StorageException("Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String store(MultipartFile file)
    {
        // Normalize file name
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try
        {
            if (file.isEmpty())
            {
                throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file " + file.getOriginalFilename());
            }
            // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
            Path targetLocation = this.rootLocation.resolve(fileName);
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            return fileName;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to store file " + file.getOriginalFilename(), e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        try
        {
            Files.createDirectory(rootLocation);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new StorageException("Could not initialize storage", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to get the code of the application. http://mkaroune.e-monsite.com/pages/spring/spring-boot-multipart-file-upload.html